# Firestore get document by Id doesn't exist but really exist

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I have a simple query like that:

```
suspend fun getRecipeById(id: String): Recipe {
    val snapshot = firebase.firestore
        .collection(RECIPE_COLLECTION)
        .document(id)
        .get()
        .await()
}
```

Im looking a document by autogenerated document id:

[image]

With the first document works, but I was trying with another one and document doesnt exist, but if I look on Firestore exist.

I debugged and the document is correct.

Comment: Without being able to see that the string in your code matches the string in the console, there's not much we can do.  If Firestore says the document doesn't exist, telling the truth.

Comment: What is RECIPE_COLLECTION?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found the problem. In my database value, I got a space behind the id. So be careful with edit manually your database to avoid make human mistakes.